# Using bash process substitution in vim

Tags: vim, process-substitution

I want to use bash process substitution from vim, how can I do that? I need I can type something like:

```
:tabe `<(git show mybranch:mydir/myfile.txt)`
```

That particular form is not valid. How can I make vim open the output of `git show mybranch:mydir/myfile.txt` command in a new tab.

Answer (score 5):

Use `:tabe` to open a new tab and

```
:r !cmd
```

to insert output of `cmd` at cursor position

Using

```
 :tabe `cmd`
```

will name the tab created with the output of the command

Answer (score 1):

```
:tabe|r!git show mybranch:mydir/myfile.txt
```

or

```
:tabe|%!git show mybranch:mydir/myfile.txt
```